# How to load data using sqlldr

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

My raw file like below, Here Transaction Branch is different and Home branch is different

[image]

I need data like below, can any one help me to archive this (using sqlldr concept)

```
Tr_Bra  Acc     Name    Bal Home_Bra
100     1000    bbbb    100 100
100     1001    bbbb    200 100
101     1003    bbbb    400 200
101     1004    bbbb    500 200
102     1005    bbbb    400 500
102     1006    bbbb    500 500
```

Comment: I'm rather lost . . . how many tables do you have?  You say you have "a raw file" but then show three different extracts.  Is that in a file, in a table, multiple files, or what?

Comment: I am not sure, how Tr_Bra related to other column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to upload the filename (ie: 100.csv) as a value for SQL Loader to load into the table, there no way for the program to identify the file name as a parameter.

I suggest concatenating the files with another script (Python would we great for the job) and then loading the final file with SQL Loader.